# flutter form data disappears when I scroll

Tags: flutter

I have a widget, that has an image element and and expanded listview of form elements that as I fill out and scroll the data disappears when it scrolls behind the image.  It is not throwing any errors when I debug and it happens on any field that scrolls behind the image at the top of the widget.  Any ideas?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _children = <Widget>[
      new Center(
        child: new Text(widget.prov.fname + widget.prov.lname,
          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      new Center(
          child: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 125.0, right: 125.0, bottom: 50.0),
            child: new Image.network('http://$baseurl:8080/getimage/'+widget.prov.pic.assetName),
          )
      ),

      new Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidate: _autovalidate,
          onWillPop: _warnUserAboutInvalidData,
          child: new Expanded(
              child: new ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                      hintText: 'First Name?',
                      labelText: 'First Name *',
                    ),
                    onSaved: (String value) { referral.fname = value; },
                    validator: _validateName,
                  ),

                  new TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                      hintText: 'Last Name?',
                      labelText: 'Last Name *',
                    ),
                    onSaved: (String value) { referral.lname = value; },
                    validator: _validateName,
                  ),

                  new TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.phone),
                        hintText: 'How to contact?',
                        labelText: 'Phone Number *',
                        prefixText: '+1'
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    onSaved: (String value) { referral.contact = value; },
                    validator: _validatePhoneNumber,
                    // TextInputFormatters are applied in sequence.
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter> [
                      WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                      // Fit the validating format.
                      _phoneNumberFormatter,
                    ],
                  ),

                  new TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Tell us about patient',
                      helperText: 'It does not have to be detailed yet',
                      labelText: 'Referral Details',
                    ),
                    maxLines: 5,
                  ),

                  new _DateTimePicker(
                    labelText: 'DOB',
                    selectedDate: _fromDate,
                    selectDate: (DateTime date) {
                      setState(() {
                        referral.dob = date;
                      });
                    },
                  ),

                  new InputDecorator(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Type of Appointment',
                      hintText: 'Choose an Appointment Type',
                    ),
                    isEmpty: _typeAppt == null,
                    child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                      value: _typeAppt,
                      isDense: true,
                      onChanged: (String newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          _typeAppt = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                      items: _allTypeAppt.map((String value) {
                        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: new Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],

              )
          )
      ),

      /*new RefreshIndicator(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
          itemCount: listcount,
        ),
        onRefresh: _onRefresh,

      ),*/

    ];
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("My Provider")),
      body: new Column(
        children: _children,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't save the values which were put into the TextFields (to a state for example).
From your code I assume you are using the ListView.builder() to set up your ListView. This method, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html), renders only the children, which are in view. Once you scroll a child out of view, it is removed from the ListView and only added again, once you scroll it into view. Because the TextField is removed, the value is removed as well.

To permanently have the value saved, I would advice to use TextFields and save the input to state in the [`onChanged()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html) method of the TextField, or make use of [TextEditingController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html).

Comment: Looks like using a controller did it, TextEditingController is available on the TextFormField and all is working now.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Robert can you share the code. How did you resolve this in the end?

Comment: Baksoy, you can instanciate a TextEditingController. And after use for example in the initState :     _textEditingControllerName.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _viewModel.name= _textEditingControllerName.value.text;
      });
    });

Comment: The problem when we set a controller to a TextFormField or a TextField i have tried both it generate another exception (duplicate GlobalKey...), See my comment here to reproduce : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11500 do you have any workaround to make it work ?

Comment: Can you provide an example code to solve this issue?

Answer (score 26):

This is because you are using ListView to render your children. ListView only renders the visible children (has recycling nature). Instead, use Column with SingleChildScrollView.

```
SingleChildScrollView(child:Column(children:yourFormChildren));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer given the OP usage of `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

Using TextEditorController it's quite simple:

For "First Name" add==>

`TextEditingController nameController = new TextEditingController();`

and

```
`new TextFormField(
         decoration: const InputDecoration(
           icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
           hintText: 'First Name?',
           labelText: 'First Name *',
          ),
         validator: _validateName,
         controller: nameController,
 ),`
```

In your onSubmit() ==>

`print(nameController.text)`

Answer (score 0):

if you have TextFormField that you auto generate by listView.builder()
you can do this solution

```
  List<TextEditingController> generalController=[];

 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
  generalController.add(TextEditingController(text: ""));
}}
```

first define list that contain list of TextEditingController
and after that initialize  it with default value inside initState
and inside every item in listview.builder()
use controller with index

like that

```
 ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context,int index){
 CustomTextFromField(
                    textEditingController: generalController[index],
                    hint: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("subject_name"),
                    texInputType: TextInputType.text,
                

                  ),
              },
          itemCount: state.subjectList.length,
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was using ListView and the values go missing when i was scroll, Just as someone above mentioned(Suman Maharjan) i tried using SingleChildScrollView with Column and issue is resolved now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).