# TextFormField value not updating as intended in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a strange problem in my application I have a signup page with several textformfields inside a ListView and the ListView is a child to the Form.

when i reach the last formfield inside the ListView i need to scroll up the screen to actually see what i am typing inside the field. When i do scroll up the textformfields which go out of focus are losing the entered text and are initialised as null. I am not sure what i am missing or do i have to use some other way to make sure i retain the TextFormField values. I have tried to use the controller in every TextFormField then it is retaining the value even if I scroll up. But, the properties of the object e.g, hostelData.hostelName are only updated first time and the changes are not reflected in the object property from the second time. I am not so sure what i am missing? Please can someone help me in solving this. 
Please excuse my mistakes in posting as i am new to programming and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have posted the code below so that you can reproduce the same problem.

```
 import 'dart:async';

 import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
 import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';     
 import 'package:myhostel/theme.dart' as Theme;
 import 'package:myhostel/globals.dart' as gl;

 class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
 const SignUp({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
 @override
  _SignUpState createState() => new _SignUpState();
  }

class HostelData{
 String hostelName = '';
 String ownersName = '';
 String mobileNumber = '';
 String emailId = '';
 String password = '';
 String city = '';
 String hostelType= 'mens';
 String confirmPassword ='';
 }
class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
 HostelData hostelData = new HostelData();

void showInSnackBar(String value) {
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
    content: new Text(value),
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),

  ));
}

final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
final GlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>> _passwordFieldKey = new 
GlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>>();
bool _autovalidate = false;
bool _formWasEdited = false;

 void _handleSubmitted() {
  final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;
 if (!form.validate()) {
   _autovalidate = true;  // Start validating on every change.
   showInSnackBar('Please fix the errors in red before submitting.');
   } else {
     form.save();
      showInSnackBar('${hostelData.ownersName}\'s hostel name is 
             ${hostelData.hostelName}');
            _createuserwithemailandpassword();
     }
   }
   String _validateName(String value) {
    _formWasEdited = true;
     if (value.isEmpty)
     return 'Name is required.';
     final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z ]+$');
     if (!nameExp.hasMatch(value))
     return 'Please enter only alphabetical characters and spaces.';
     return null;
    }
    String _validatePassword(String value) {
      _formWasEdited = true;
       final FormFieldState<String> passwordField = 
       _passwordFieldKey.currentState;
     if (passwordField.value == null || passwordField.value.isEmpty)
     return 'Please choose a password.';
    if (passwordField.value != value)
     return 'Passwords don\'t match';
     return null;
      }
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context){

   return new MaterialApp(
   theme: Theme.MyHostelThemeData,
   home: new Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,

    body: new Container(
      child: new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage('assets/bg.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
      ),
      child: new Form(

        key: _formKey,
        autovalidate: _autovalidate,


       child: new ListView(
         children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:32.0),
            child: new Center(
              child: new Text('SIGN UP',
              style: new TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFFF5FEFD),fontSize:24.0,fontWeight: 
             FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          ),
      new Row(
            children:[


      new Expanded(
      child: new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0,right: 12.0,),

        child:new TextFormField(decoration: new InputDecoration(
            /*hintStyle: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,color: const Color(0xFFF5FEFD),),*/
            labelText: 'Hostel Name',
          ),
          /*style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            color:  Colors.white,
          ),*/

          onSaved:(String value){ hostelData.hostelName = value; },
          validator: _validateName,
         ),
       ),
      ),
     ],
     ),
     new Row(
            children:[
              /*new Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                width: 24.0,
                child: new Image.asset(
                  'assets/person_avatar.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  //alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                ),
              ),*/

              new Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0,right: 12.0,),

                  child:new TextFormField(
                    //controller: _ownersNameController,

                    decoration: new InputDecoration(//hintText: 'Mobile 
             Number',
                     /* hintStyle: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: const 
          Color(0xFFF5FEFD),),*/
                      labelText: 'Owners Name',
                    ),

                    /*style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color:  Colors.white,
                    ),*/
                 onSaved: (String value) { hostelData.ownersName = value; 
                                                                        },
                    validator: _validateName,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ), 
       new Row(
            children:[



              new Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0,right: 12.0,),

                  child:new TextFormField(
                    //controller: _mobileNumberController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,

                    decoration: new InputDecoration(//hintText: 'Mobile 
                     Number',
                      /* hintStyle: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: 
                        const Color(0xFFF5FEFD),),*/
                      labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                      //prefixText: '+91',
                    ),

                    /*style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color:  Colors.white,
                    ),*/
               onSaved: (String value) { hostelData.mobileNumber = value; },
                    //validator: _validatePhoneNumber,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
      //implements EmailID Row
          new Row(
            children:[


              new Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0,right: 12.0,),

                  child:new TextFormField(
                    //controller: _emailIdController,

                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      //hintText: 'Mobile Number',
                      /*hintStyle: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: const 
                            Color(0xFFF5FEFD),),*/
                      labelText: 'EMail Id',
                      helperText: 'Required',
                    ),
                    /*style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color:  Colors.white,
                    ),*/
                    onSaved: (String value){hostelData.emailId = value;},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
      //implements the password row

          new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0,),
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                  //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new Icon(Icons.lock_outline,
                      color: const Color(0xFFF5FEFD)
                  ),
                ),
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 28.0, right: 12.0,),
                    child: new TextFormField(
                      key: _passwordFieldKey,
                      //controller: _passwordController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'min 8 characters',
                        labelText: 'Password',
                          helperText: 'Required',

                      ),
                      autocorrect: false,
                      //obscureText: true,
                      //validator: 'Required',
                      /*style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.merge(new 
                                       TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: CustomColors.fontColor,
                            ),
                            ),*/
                      onSaved: (String value){hostelData.password = value;},

                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
           new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0,),
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                  //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new Icon(Icons.lock_outline,
                      color: const Color(0xFFF5FEFD)
                  ),
                ),
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 28.0, right: 12.0,),
                    child: new TextFormField(
                      //controller: _confirmpasswordcontroller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Confirm Password',
                       helperText: 'Required'


                      ),
                      autocorrect: false,
                     // obscureText: true,
                      //validator: 'Required',
                      /*style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.merge(new 
                    TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: CustomColors.fontColor,
                            ),
                            ),*/
                      //onSaved: (String value){hostelData.confirmPassword = 
                                                value;},

                      validator: _validatePassword,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Row(
            children:[

              new Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0,right: 12.0,),

                  child:new TextFormField(
                    controller: _cityController,

                    decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'City*'),

                    onSaved: (String value){hostelData.city = value;},
                    validator: _validateName,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
         new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left:24.0,right: 24.0),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              border: new Border.all(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: 2.0,
              ),
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(const 
                    Radius.circular(32.0),)
            ),
        child: new FlatButton(
          onPressed: ((){
            print('SignUp Button Clicked');
             _handleSubmitted();
          }),
          child: new Text (
            'SIGN UP',
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
       ),
          new Row(
            children:[


                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0,bottom: 12.0),

                  child:new Text(
                    'Already have an account?',
                       style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color:  Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              new Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0,top: 
                    4.0,bottom:16.0),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0,left: 4.0),
                child:
              new MaterialButton(
                onPressed: ((){
                //Sign In Button pressed declaration here
                print('sign in button clicked');

              }),
                  child: new Text('SignIn',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: Colors.teal[200],
                    ),
                     ),
                minWidth: 16.0,
              ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
            child: new Text('* indicates required field',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),),
          ),
       ]
      ),
       ),
      ),

     ),

    ),

    );

  } // widget ends here
```

globals.dart

```
library my_hostel.globals;

 import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
 import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';



   final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

 final DatabaseReference messagesRef =FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
```

Comment: You're missing controllers for the text fields. Here is the docu on TextEditingControllers: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html The ListView removes children which are out of view for performance reasons and adds them again once they are in view again. Without the controllers the text fields are initialized with an empty string. I fell like I've answered that before. I will post the link once I found it.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240734/flutter-form-data-disappears-when-i-scroll/45242235#45242235

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought about this and realised that i was losing the string values as I've not used the controllers and then tried it with controllers. 'Voila' it worked, but the joy was only short lived as when i edit the fields again the new values are not written to the object fields like in the example hostelData.hostelName, hostelData.emailId etc., only the first value is assigned not the changes that are done later. I am really sorry i didn't see your previous answer, but thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of working code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String s1 = "";
  String s2 = "";
  String s3 = "";
  String s4 = "";
  String s5 = "";

  final TextEditingController c1 = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController c2 = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController c3 = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController c4 = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController c5 = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Example"),),
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(70.0),),
          new TextField(
            controller: c1,
            onChanged: (String text) {
              s1 = text;
            },
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(70.0),),
          new TextField(
            controller: c2,
            onChanged: (String text) {
              s2 = text;
            },
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(70.0),),
          new TextField(
            controller: c3,
            onChanged: (String text) {
              s3 = text;
            },
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(70.0),),
          new TextField(
            controller: c4,
            onChanged: (String text) {
              s4 = text;
            },
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(70.0),),
          new TextField(
            controller: c5,
            onChanged: (String text) {
              s5 = text;
            },
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

You need to add a `TextEditingController` with your `TextField`. `Listview` removes invisible widgets because rendering a ton of widgets that are not being displayed would make it perform worse!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought about this and realised that i was losing the string values as I've not used the controllers and then tried it with controllers. 'Voila' it worked, but the joy was only short lived as when i edit the fields the new values are not written to the strings like in your case s1, s2 etc only the first value is assigned not the changes that are done later.

Comment: Notice that I use `onChanged` in my `TextField`s. This `onChanged` method gets triggered every time the text changes, so not only when you hit return. That should fix your issue!

Comment: hi Bram, Thanks for your reply, I wanted to use the validator property for the text field so i went for the TextFormField. I will be trying to find the answer and i hope i will get there. thank you.

Comment: @Mahi Alright, don't forgot to hit that checkmark if it worked!