# Losing state of each form field when the form is scrolled off screen?

Tags: flutter

How can I can **save state of each form field when the form is scrolled off screen?** I lose the values I typed in the **TextFormFields** when I scroll up and the fields are off the screen.

I have heard the suggestion of saving it in controller and then assigning to initialvalue of TextFormField as seen in the code but it doesn't work for me. What am I missing?

```
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Enter Vehicle'),
      ),
      body: new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: new Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: new ListView(children: <Widget>[
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Vehicle Number'),
                  controller: _controller,
                  initialValue: _controller.text,
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Tag'),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Make'),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Model'),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Year'),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Vehicle Type'),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Location'),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Fuel'),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Other'),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Your password'),
                  validator: (val) =>
                  val.length < 6 ? 'Password too short.' : null,
                  onSaved: (val) => _password = val,
                  obscureText: true,
                ),
                new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: _submit,
                  child: new Text('Login'),
                ),
              ],)
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two solutions for this:

1. Prevent the objects from recycling
2. Save the state in the parent widget

So, while a FormField - of which TextFormField derives - is stateful, putting it in a list - of any description - will risk rebuilding it.

**Option 1:**

Change the `List` to a `Column` and wrap it in a `List` or `SingleChildListView`, its quick and hacky but might have some performance issues for lots of items

```dart
List(
   children: [...]
)
```

nb. if you have a listview.builder you are gonna need to map it out and not use the builder, or progress to option 2.

to

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
       children: [...]
   )
)
```

**Option 2:**

Create a controller for each field and save it in the parent widget, or save the data to a map and set its initial data. You can work it out but either way you need to save it in the parent widget.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use initialValue that way when using a TextFormField. In fact, if `_controller.text` is null it will give an assertion error.

To have correctly working TextFormFields ensure that:

- You are using a different TextEditingController on each of the fields.
- You are disposing your TextEditingController after being done.
- Your form is inside a StatefulWidget.

Working example:

```dart
class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyFormState createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  TextEditingController _vehicleNumber;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _vehicleNumber = new TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _vehicleNumber.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Enter Vehicle'),
      ),
      body: new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: new Form(
              child: new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextFormField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Vehicle Number'),
                controller: _vehicleNumber,
              ),
              // All the other fields here
              // All should have its own controller
            ],
          ))),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a dedicated `TextEditingController` for each `TextFormField` and I don't think you need to have the `initialValue` attribute on the fields.

Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45242235/6414732, that may help as well.

Comment: That looks like a huge pain. It's easier to _not_ use form fields and instead make a custom "react-form".

Comment: Or maybe don't use a ListView which removes elements from the widget tree once they are out of sight. As long as the list is not hundreds of fields long, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Actually I'd already tried that. I have a TextEditingController on each TextFormField. Inside build(), I assigned each field's controller to the pertinent field values and then assigned each field value to the pertaining TextFormField's  initialvalue. However, even with all that, it still doesn't work unless **setState** is called to persist values. It doesn't feel right. I know they have open tickets to improve how Forms are handled. This was a bigger deal to get working than I thought. A better solution will probably arise at some point. In the meantime, I'll make do with my hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),
                  child: new EnsureVisibleWhenFocused(
                    focusNode: _focusNode_nooftickets,
                    child: new TextFormField(
                      controller: _ticketscontroller,
                      initialValue: _ticketscontroller.text,
                      focusNode: _focusNode_nooftickets,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      validator: validatenooftickets,
                      onSaved: (String value) {
                        ticketmode.nooftickets = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a column instead of ListView and wrapped it with a singleChildScrollView and it works