# Form data disappears on scroll Flutter

Tags: forms, dart, textfield, flutter

I have implemented a form with a few TextFormFields. When i scroll the form the TextFormFields that are out of the view loses entered data. There is a similar question already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240734/flutter-form-data-disappears-when-i-scroll). I have to no idea how to use a TextEditingController to save the state, since I am pretty new to Dart and Flutter. 
I even tried using FormFieldStatePersistor following this [github repo](https://github.com/rickbsgu/rbtile_formfield_demo). That also didn't work.  Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided a solution for this in this link on github [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11500#issuecomment-366081617). Yes, @HemanthRaj is absolutely right to use the `TextEditingControllers` but if you have so many fields inside a `ListView` this approach doesn't work as the `ListView` only loads the fields to be shown and purges these fields if scrolled out of view. I have explained a proper solution in the link provided. Please check it out and the solution works perfectly.

Regards,
Mahi

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who looking for a quick answer @Mahi's post: use SingleChildScrollView and Column instead of ListView:

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
     .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `TextEditingController` in the View which hold the `Form`. And then pass it to the `controller` property of `TextFormField`.

Example:

```
// Create a controller for username field
TextEditingController _userController = new TextEditingController();
```

then

```
new TextFormField(
    controller: _userController,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      ...
    ),
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried doing the same thing, but this doesn't save the entered values on scroll.

Comment: Where are you defining the TextEditingController

Comment: Inside the subclass of statefull widget.

`class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  ....
  static final TextEditingController _userID = new TextEditingController();
  static final TextEditingController _firstName = new TextEditingController();
  static final TextEditingController _lastName = new TextEditingController();
  static final TextEditingController _email = new TextEditingController();
  static final TextEditingController _password = new TextEditingController();
  static final TextEditingController _confirmPassword =
      new TextEditingController();
         .......
`