# Flutter: TextFormField validator not called when field is not visible in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have had the same issue of [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240734/flutter-form-data-disappears-when-i-scroll) and I solved by following provided advice (I call `setState()` in the `onChanged`)... the problem is that in my case the `validator` function is not called if the field is not visible in the view (if you scroll the view until it's not displayed anymore), so I can submit the form in an invalid state.

How am I supposed to trigger validation for fields that aren't currently displayed in the `ListView`?

UPDATE:

The following is a simple demonstration of the issue (which I'm using to debug in an isolated simple app):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return _MyFormState();
  }
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final Map<int, String> model = Map<int, String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState()');
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      model[i] = null;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  String validate(String value) {
    return value.isEmpty ? 'Cannot be blank!' : null;
  }

  void submitForm() {
    final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;

    if (formState.validate()) {
      print('form is valid');
      formState.save();
    } else {
      print('form is invalid');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> fields = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      Widget widget = TextFormField(
        initialValue: model[i],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'field $i',
        ),
        validator: validate,
        onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
          print('field $i onFieldSubmitted()');
          setState(() {
            model[i] = value;
          });
        },
        onChanged: (String value) {
          print('field $i onChanged()');
          setState(() {
            model[i] = value;
          });
        },
        onSaved: (String value) {
          print('field $i onSaved()');
          setState(() {
            model[i] = value;
          });
        },
      );
      fields.add(widget);
    }

    fields.add(RaisedButton(
      child: Text('save'),
      onPressed: submitForm,
    ));

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ListView(
        children: fields,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('form test'),
        ),
        body: MyForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is simple, just don't use `ListView` but instead rely on `SingleChildScrollView` (and pass the form itself as child)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return _MyFormState();
  }
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  final Map<int, String> model = Map<int, String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState()');
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      model[i] = null;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  String validate(String value) {
    return value.isEmpty ? 'Cannot be blank!' : null;
  }

  void submitForm() {
    final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;

    if (formState.validate()) {
      print('form is valid');
      formState.save();
    } else {
      print('form is invalid');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> fields = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      Widget widget = TextFormField(
        initialValue: model[i],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'field $i',
        ),
        validator: validate,
        onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
          print('field $i onFieldSubmitted()');
          setState(() {
            model[i] = value;
          });
        },
      );
      fields.add(widget);
    }

    fields.add(RaisedButton(
      child: Text('save'),
      onPressed: submitForm,
    ));

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: fields,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('form test'),
        ),
        body: MyForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do it
1) You can't use the validator. Use a validation method from the provider. If the provider sends back an error show a snackbar.
2) You can use the validator. You have to use the validation method in the provider as well. If provider returns an error, use scrollcontroller to scroll to the required list element and hopefully form field validator will get activated at that time.

Comment: What do you mean by "provider"? this one -> https://pub.dev/packages/provider ?

Comment: If you don't want to use provider.. you can write the validation logic in a separate method in the widget class.

Comment: the problem is not in the validation logic, all the fields validators are working fine if the fields are visible in the view... the point is that if the field is not visible, the `FormState`'s `validate()` does not call validators of hidden fields (in other words it's like the validate is done against a portion of the form instead of the full one)

Comment: After calling the validate() if the field is scrolled into view, does it shows the error?

Comment: yep, as I wrote validation is working fine provided that the fields are currently displayed in the view

Comment: I've added a full sample code that demonstrate my scenario

Comment: validator method alone won't cut it. To stop the form from submitting if there is an error, in the submit() you will need to stop from going further. For that each form field will need its own TextEditingController(which is a constructor prop). You can check if each controller has the text it was fed even if when the field is out of view. You can check it inside the submit(). I will basically work with such workaround since no straight solution is present. I will also try it.